# Sidekiq job get stuck in "busy"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq, ruby-on-rails-6

For some time now my sidekiq keeps getting stuck and us not executing jobs in my development environment. They are stuck in "busy" and it seems to be arbitrary because I tried it with different jobs and sometimes they run and then they stop, even after restarting sidekiq and clearing the queue with 'redis-cli FLUSHALL`.

I researched and with `kill -TTIN pid` I got a backtrace but I don't even know what to look for. Find the logs down below.

Other assumptions I have/things I changed before it happened:

- I had cron jobs running locally, which worked fine
- Changed concurrecny from 10 to 50 and then back to 10
- upgraded to Rails 6
- Something with redis?

I really appreciate any help, as it is blocking me :(

```
/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/monitor.rb:114:in `sleep'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/monitor.rb:114:in `wait'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/monitor.rb:114:in `block (2 levels) in wait'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/monitor.rb:113:in `handle_interrupt'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/monitor.rb:113:in `block in wait'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/monitor.rb:109:in `handle_interrupt'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/monitor.rb:109:in `wait'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/monitor.rb:128:in `wait_while'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/concurrency/share_lock.rb:221:in `wait_for'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/concurrency/share_lock.rb:83:in `block (2 levels) in start_exclusive'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/concurrency/share_lock.rb:187:in `yield_shares'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/concurrency/share_lock.rb:82:in `block in start_exclusive'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/monitor.rb:235:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/concurrency/share_lock.rb:77:in `start_exclusive'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/concurrency/share_lock.rb:149:in `exclusive'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:13:in `loading'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:40:in `load_interlock'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:390:in `require_or_load'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:545:in `load_missing_constant'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `const_missing'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:582:in `load_missing_constant'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `const_missing'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:582:in `load_missing_constant'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `const_missing'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actiontext-6.0.0/lib/action_text/engine.rb:46:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:72:in `class_eval'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:72:in `block in execute_hook'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:62:in `with_execution_control'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:67:in `execute_hook'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:52:in `block in run_load_hooks'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:51:in `each'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:51:in `run_load_hooks'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actiontext-6.0.0/lib/action_text/content.rb:132:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:325:in `require'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:325:in `block in require'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:325:in `require'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actiontext-6.0.0/lib/action_text/engine.rb:42:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:429:in `instance_exec'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:429:in `block in make_lambda'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:201:in `block (2 levels) in halting'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:607:in `block (2 levels) in default_terminator'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:606:in `catch'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:606:in `block in default_terminator'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:202:in `block in halting'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:514:in `block in invoke_before'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:514:in `each'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:514:in `invoke_before'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:134:in `run_callbacks'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/execution_wrapper.rb:111:in `run!'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/execution_wrapper.rb:73:in `block in run!'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/execution_wrapper.rb:70:in `tap'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/execution_wrapper.rb:70:in `run!'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/execution_wrapper.rb:86:in `wrap'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/reloader.rb:71:in `wrap'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sidekiq-6.0.7/lib/sidekiq/rails.rb:42:in `call'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sidekiq-6.0.7/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:131:in `block (4 levels) in dispatch'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sidekiq-6.0.7/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:257:in `stats'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sidekiq-6.0.7/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:126:in `block (3 levels) in dispatch'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sidekiq-6.0.7/lib/sidekiq/job_logger.rb:13:in `call'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sidekiq-6.0.7/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:125:in `block (2 levels) in dispatch'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sidekiq-6.0.7/lib/sidekiq/job_retry.rb:78:in `global'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sidekiq-6.0.7/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:124:in `block in dispatch'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sidekiq-6.0.7/lib/sidekiq/logger.rb:10:in `with'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sidekiq-6.0.7/lib/sidekiq/job_logger.rb:33:in `prepare'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sidekiq-6.0.7/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:123:in `dispatch'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sidekiq-6.0.7/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:162:in `process'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sidekiq-6.0.7/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:78:in `process_one'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sidekiq-6.0.7/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:68:in `run'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sidekiq-6.0.7/lib/sidekiq/util.rb:15:in `watchdog'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sidekiq-6.0.7/lib/sidekiq/util.rb:24:in `block in safe_thread'
2020-05-13T20:24:27.362Z pid=2993 tid=ovu5fxgf9 WARN: Thread TID-ovu5k041l processor
2020-05-13T20:24:27.362Z pid=2993 tid=ovu5fxgf9 WARN: /Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/redis-4.1.4/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:69:in `select'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/redis-4.1.4/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:69:in `rescue in _read_from_socket'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/redis-4.1.4/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:65:in `_read_from_socket'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/redis-4.1.4/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:57:in `gets'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/redis-4.1.4/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:396:in `read'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/redis-4.1.4/lib/redis/client.rb:273:in `block in read'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/redis-4.1.4/lib/redis/client.rb:261:in `io'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/redis-4.1.4/lib/redis/client.rb:272:in `read'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/redis-4.1.4/lib/redis/client.rb:125:in `block in call'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/redis-4.1.4/lib/redis/client.rb:241:in `block (2 levels) in process'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/redis-4.1.4/lib/redis/client.rb:385:in `ensure_connected'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/redis-4.1.4/lib/redis/client.rb:231:in `block in process'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/redis-4.1.4/lib/redis/client.rb:320:in `logging'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/redis-4.1.4/lib/redis/client.rb:230:in `process'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/redis-4.1.4/lib/redis/client.rb:125:in `call'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/redis-4.1.4/lib/redis/client.rb:219:in `block in call_with_timeout'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/redis-4.1.4/lib/redis/client.rb:293:in `with_socket_timeout'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/redis-4.1.4/lib/redis/client.rb:218:in `call_with_timeout'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/redis-4.1.4/lib/redis.rb:1187:in `block in _bpop'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/redis-4.1.4/lib/redis.rb:51:in `block in synchronize'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/monitor.rb:235:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/redis-4.1.4/lib/redis.rb:51:in `synchronize'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/redis-4.1.4/lib/redis.rb:1184:in `_bpop'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/redis-4.1.4/lib/redis.rb:1229:in `brpop'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sidekiq-6.0.7/lib/sidekiq/fetch.rb:37:in `block in retrieve_work'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sidekiq-6.0.7/lib/sidekiq.rb:97:in `block in redis'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/connection_pool-2.2.2/lib/connection_pool.rb:65:in `block (2 levels) in with'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/connection_pool-2.2.2/lib/connection_pool.rb:64:in `handle_interrupt'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/connection_pool-2.2.2/lib/connection_pool.rb:64:in `block in with'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/connection_pool-2.2.2/lib/connection_pool.rb:61:in `handle_interrupt'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/connection_pool-2.2.2/lib/connection_pool.rb:61:in `with'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sidekiq-6.0.7/lib/sidekiq.rb:94:in `redis'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sidekiq-6.0.7/lib/sidekiq/fetch.rb:37:in `retrieve_work'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sidekiq-6.0.7/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:83:in `get_one'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sidekiq-6.0.7/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:95:in `fetch'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sidekiq-6.0.7/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:77:in `process_one'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sidekiq-6.0.7/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:68:in `run'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sidekiq-6.0.7/lib/sidekiq/util.rb:15:in `watchdog'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sidekiq-6.0.7/lib/sidekiq/util.rb:24:in `block in safe_thread'
2020-05-13T20:24:27.363Z pid=2993 tid=ovu5fxgf9 WARN: Thread TID-ovu5k049h processor
2020-05-13T20:24:27.363Z pid=2993 tid=ovu5fxgf9 WARN: /Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/redis-4.1.4/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:69:in `select'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/redis-4.1.4/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:69:in `rescue in _read_from_socket'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/redis-4.1.4/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:65:in `_read_from_socket'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/redis-4.1.4/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:57:in `gets'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/redis-4.1.4/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:396:in `read'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/redis-4.1.4/lib/redis/client.rb:273:in `block in read'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/redis-4.1.4/lib/redis/client.rb:261:in `io'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/redis-4.1.4/lib/redis/client.rb:272:in `read'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/redis-4.1.4/lib/redis/client.rb:125:in `block in call'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/redis-4.1.4/lib/redis/client.rb:241:in `block (2 levels) in process'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/redis-4.1.4/lib/redis/client.rb:385:in `ensure_connected'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/redis-4.1.4/lib/redis/client.rb:231:in `block in process'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/redis-4.1.4/lib/redis/client.rb:320:in `logging'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/redis-4.1.4/lib/redis/client.rb:230:in `process'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/redis-4.1.4/lib/redis/client.rb:125:in `call'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/redis-4.1.4/lib/redis/client.rb:219:in `block in call_with_timeout'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/redis-4.1.4/lib/redis/client.rb:293:in `with_socket_timeout'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/redis-4.1.4/lib/redis/client.rb:218:in `call_with_timeout'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/redis-4.1.4/lib/redis.rb:1187:in `block in _bpop'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/redis-4.1.4/lib/redis.rb:51:in `block in synchronize'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/monitor.rb:235:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/redis-4.1.4/lib/redis.rb:51:in `synchronize'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/redis-4.1.4/lib/redis.rb:1184:in `_bpop'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/redis-4.1.4/lib/redis.rb:1229:in `brpop'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sidekiq-6.0.7/lib/sidekiq/fetch.rb:37:in `block in retrieve_work'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sidekiq-6.0.7/lib/sidekiq.rb:97:in `block in redis'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/connection_pool-2.2.2/lib/connection_pool.rb:65:in `block (2 levels) in with'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/connection_pool-2.2.2/lib/connection_pool.rb:64:in `handle_interrupt'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/connection_pool-2.2.2/lib/connection_pool.rb:64:in `block in with'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/connection_pool-2.2.2/lib/connection_pool.rb:61:in `handle_interrupt'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/connection_pool-2.2.2/lib/connection_pool.rb:61:in `with'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sidekiq-6.0.7/lib/sidekiq.rb:94:in `redis'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sidekiq-6.0.7/lib/sidekiq/fetch.rb:37:in `retrieve_work'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sidekiq-6.0.7/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:83:in `get_one'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sidekiq-6.0.7/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:95:in `fetch'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sidekiq-6.0.7/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:77:in `process_one'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sidekiq-6.0.7/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:68:in `run'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sidekiq-6.0.7/lib/sidekiq/util.rb:15:in `watchdog'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sidekiq-6.0.7/lib/sidekiq/util.rb:24:in `block in safe_thread'
2020-05-13T20:24:27.363Z pid=2993 tid=ovu5fxgf9 WARN: Thread TID-ovu5k04dx scheduler
2020-05-13T20:24:27.363Z pid=2993 tid=ovu5fxgf9 WARN: /Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/connection_pool-2.2.2/lib/connection_pool/timed_stack.rb:88:in `sleep'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/connection_pool-2.2.2/lib/connection_pool/timed_stack.rb:88:in `wait'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/connection_pool-2.2.2/lib/connection_pool/timed_stack.rb:88:in `block (2 levels) in pop'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/connection_pool-2.2.2/lib/connection_pool/timed_stack.rb:79:in `loop'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/connection_pool-2.2.2/lib/connection_pool/timed_stack.rb:79:in `block in pop'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/connection_pool-2.2.2/lib/connection_pool/timed_stack.rb:78:in `synchronize'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/connection_pool-2.2.2/lib/connection_pool/timed_stack.rb:78:in `pop'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sidekiq-6.0.7/lib/sidekiq/scheduled.rb:89:in `wait'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sidekiq-6.0.7/lib/sidekiq/scheduled.rb:71:in `block in start'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sidekiq-6.0.7/lib/sidekiq/util.rb:15:in `watchdog'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sidekiq-6.0.7/lib/sidekiq/util.rb:24:in `block in safe_thread'
2020-05-13T20:24:27.363Z pid=2993 tid=ovu5fxgf9 WARN: Thread TID-ovu5egk7d
2020-05-13T20:24:27.363Z pid=2993 tid=ovu5fxgf9 WARN: /Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rb-fsevent-0.10.4/lib/rb-fsevent/fsevent.rb:44:in `select'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rb-fsevent-0.10.4/lib/rb-fsevent/fsevent.rb:44:in `run'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/listen-3.0.8/lib/listen/adapter/darwin.rb:68:in `_run_worker'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/listen-3.0.8/lib/listen/adapter/darwin.rb:77:in `block (2 levels) in _run_workers_in_background'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/listen-3.0.8/lib/listen/internals/thread_pool.rb:6:in `block in add'
2020-05-13T20:24:27.363Z pid=2993 tid=ovu5fxgf9 WARN: Thread TID-ovu5egkj5
2020-05-13T20:24:27.363Z pid=2993 tid=ovu5fxgf9 WARN: /Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rb-fsevent-0.10.4/lib/rb-fsevent/fsevent.rb:44:in `select'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rb-fsevent-0.10.4/lib/rb-fsevent/fsevent.rb:44:in `run'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/listen-3.0.8/lib/listen/adapter/darwin.rb:68:in `_run_worker'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/listen-3.0.8/lib/listen/adapter/darwin.rb:77:in `block (2 levels) in _run_workers_in_background'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/listen-3.0.8/lib/listen/internals/thread_pool.rb:6:in `block in add'
2020-05-13T20:24:27.363Z pid=2993 tid=ovu5fxgf9 WARN: Thread TID-ovu5egkv5
2020-05-13T20:24:27.363Z pid=2993 tid=ovu5fxgf9 WARN: /Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rb-fsevent-0.10.4/lib/rb-fsevent/fsevent.rb:44:in `select'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rb-fsevent-0.10.4/lib/rb-fsevent/fsevent.rb:44:in `run'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/listen-3.0.8/lib/listen/adapter/darwin.rb:68:in `_run_worker'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/listen-3.0.8/lib/listen/adapter/darwin.rb:77:in `block (2 levels) in _run_workers_in_background'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/listen-3.0.8/lib/listen/internals/thread_pool.rb:6:in `block in add'
2020-05-13T20:24:27.363Z pid=2993 tid=ovu5fxgf9 WARN: Thread TID-ovu5egjkd
2020-05-13T20:24:27.363Z pid=2993 tid=ovu5fxgf9 WARN: /Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rb-fsevent-0.10.4/lib/rb-fsevent/fsevent.rb:44:in `select'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rb-fsevent-0.10.4/lib/rb-fsevent/fsevent.rb:44:in `run'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/listen-3.0.8/lib/listen/adapter/darwin.rb:68:in `_run_worker'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/listen-3.0.8/lib/listen/adapter/darwin.rb:77:in `block (2 levels) in _run_workers_in_background'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/listen-3.0.8/lib/listen/internals/thread_pool.rb:6:in `block in add'
2020-05-13T20:24:27.363Z pid=2993 tid=ovu5fxgf9 WARN: Thread TID-ovu5egk01
2020-05-13T20:24:27.363Z pid=2993 tid=ovu5fxgf9 WARN: /Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rb-fsevent-0.10.4/lib/rb-fsevent/fsevent.rb:44:in `select'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rb-fsevent-0.10.4/lib/rb-fsevent/fsevent.rb:44:in `run'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/listen-3.0.8/lib/listen/adapter/darwin.rb:68:in `_run_worker'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/listen-3.0.8/lib/listen/adapter/darwin.rb:77:in `block (2 levels) in _run_workers_in_background'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/listen-3.0.8/lib/listen/internals/thread_pool.rb:6:in `block in add'
2020-05-13T20:24:27.364Z pid=2993 tid=ovu5fxgf9 WARN: Thread TID-ovu5egk2h
2020-05-13T20:24:27.364Z pid=2993 tid=ovu5fxgf9 WARN: /Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rb-fsevent-0.10.4/lib/rb-fsevent/fsevent.rb:44:in `select'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rb-fsevent-0.10.4/lib/rb-fsevent/fsevent.rb:44:in `run'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/listen-3.0.8/lib/listen/adapter/darwin.rb:68:in `_run_worker'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/listen-3.0.8/lib/listen/adapter/darwin.rb:77:in `block (2 levels) in _run_workers_in_background'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/listen-3.0.8/lib/listen/internals/thread_pool.rb:6:in `block in add'
2020-05-13T20:24:27.364Z pid=2993 tid=ovu5fxgf9 WARN: Thread TID-ovu67uhyx
2020-05-13T20:24:27.364Z pid=2993 tid=ovu5fxgf9 WARN: /Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rb-fsevent-0.10.4/lib/rb-fsevent/fsevent.rb:44:in `select'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rb-fsevent-0.10.4/lib/rb-fsevent/fsevent.rb:44:in `run'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/listen-3.0.8/lib/listen/adapter/darwin.rb:68:in `_run_worker'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/listen-3.0.8/lib/listen/adapter/darwin.rb:77:in `block (2 levels) in _run_workers_in_background'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/listen-3.0.8/lib/listen/internals/thread_pool.rb:6:in `block in add'
2020-05-13T20:24:27.364Z pid=2993 tid=ovu5fxgf9 WARN: Thread TID-ovu67ui6h
2020-05-13T20:24:27.364Z pid=2993 tid=ovu5fxgf9 WARN: /Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rb-fsevent-0.10.4/lib/rb-fsevent/fsevent.rb:44:in `select'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rb-fsevent-0.10.4/lib/rb-fsevent/fsevent.rb:44:in `run'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/listen-3.0.8/lib/listen/adapter/darwin.rb:68:in `_run_worker'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/listen-3.0.8/lib/listen/adapter/darwin.rb:77:in `block (2 levels) in _run_workers_in_background'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/listen-3.0.8/lib/listen/internals/thread_pool.rb:6:in `block in add'
2020-05-13T20:24:27.364Z pid=2993 tid=ovu5fxgf9 WARN: Thread TID-ovu67uif1
2020-05-13T20:24:27.364Z pid=2993 tid=ovu5fxgf9 WARN: /Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rb-fsevent-0.10.4/lib/rb-fsevent/fsevent.rb:44:in `select'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rb-fsevent-0.10.4/lib/rb-fsevent/fsevent.rb:44:in `run'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/listen-3.0.8/lib/listen/adapter/darwin.rb:68:in `_run_worker'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/listen-3.0.8/lib/listen/adapter/darwin.rb:77:in `block (2 levels) in _run_workers_in_background'
/Users/claramorgeneyer/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/listen-3.0.8/lib/listen/internals/thread_pool.rb:6:in `block in add
```

Comment: Are there any [similar issues](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/issues?q=stuck+busy) in issue tracker of Sidekiq?

Comment: I bet I searched in the issues, but I must have overlooked this one: 
https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/issues/4216 . Now I changed to `config.load_defaults "6.0"` and it seems to work fine.

Comment: That's good news 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For any one running into the same issue:

After upgrading to Rails 6, I didn't change the auto loader to zeitwerk by mistake.

Find some more information here: [issue on Sidekiq repo](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/issues/4216)

Change this in:

```
# application.rb

...
  config.load_defaults "6.0"
...
```

You can also test if you have zeitwerk enabled with

```
rails zeitwerk:check
```